# Generate CSV file from javascript under IE11

Tags: jquery, export-to-csv

I read lot of sample to generate csv file from data and push it to download to export it.

```
 let csvContent = '';
                $.each(msg.d.LstObj[0], function (key, element) { csvContent += (csvContent === '' ? '' : ',') + key; });
                csvContent += "\n";
                msg.d.LstObj.forEach(function (rowArray) {
                    var row = '';
                    $.each(rowArray, function (key, element) { row += (row === '' ? '' : ',') + element; });
                    csvContent += row + "\n";
                });
                var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
                hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(csvContent);
                hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
                hiddenElement.download = 'people.csv';
                hiddenElement.click();
```

Under Chrome FF : ok
Under IE11 : no download just a message ask me :

> voulez vous autoriser ce site web à ouvrir une application

And just one choise windows store...
Someone have an idea??? I put my code in "site de confiance"...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the block I use to satisfy all browsers, IE 11 included and it works great for me:

```
if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    //Internet Explorer
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(new Blob([result]), csvFileName);
} else if (window.webkitURL != null) {
    //Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    result = encodeURIComponent(result);
    a.href = "data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8," + result;
    a.download = csvFileName;
    a.click();
} else if (navigator.appName === "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
    //Internet Explorer 8 and 9
    var oWin = window.open();
    oWin.document.write("sep=,\r\n" + result);
    oWin.document.close();
    oWin.document.execCommand("SaveAs", true, csvFileName);
    oWin.close();
} else {
    //Everything Else
    window.open(result);
}
```

Comment: Just a little correction to [open excel in UTF-8 ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549723/generate-csv-file-from-javascript-with-special-characters)