# Generating HTML file (or Zip with html inside) for user to download

Tags: javascript

I want to create a website, where user fills out the form and after submitting I want to generate a html file for him with the data he filled and then allow him to download this file.

Is it possible with JS without server side JS?

Comment: Why not email this to the user instead of downloading? Downloading files (especially without the user asking for it, eg. a download page, is not a smart idea)

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16895271/7377521

Comment: u can take somme goods ideas in this post [Generate csv file in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50536028/generate-csv-file-from-javascript-under-ie11)

Comment: Client wants it to be downloadable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a link where href property is an encoded URI.

```js
let exampleText ="My Name\nMy Surname\nMy Town\n"
let localfile = "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(exampleText);

document.getElementById("linkfile").setAttribute("href", localfile);
```

```html
<a id="linkfile" download="myInfo.txt">Click here to download</a>
```

Comment: Sound like a cimple enough solution, will test and check as accepted if it's gonna do the trick!

Comment: Could you validate the answer, please

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it JUST frontend side. You could use [zip.js](https://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/) to convert those files into a zip, then convert it into a binary array, then convert it into a blob file, and prompt for download using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server) question.

You may have to casts your html files into DOM "File"s, this might be very slow on mobile since all processing will be done on client side.